# Can't cast View from ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to cast a ProgressDialog from XML.

```
ProgressDialog progressBar =(ProgressDialog)findViewById(R.id.progressBar_first);
```

But this error occured:

```
Cannot cast from View to ProgressDialog
```

My XML layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/first_page" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_first"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me guys!

Comment: you are defining Progress bar and casting it to progress dialog 
type mismatch causing you error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write like this :**

```
ProgressBar progressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar_first);
```

Answer (score 1):

you  should change it with:

```
ProgressBar progressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar_first);
```